# 200 Status Response After Deploying .NET Core 3.1 Web App to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

Anyone come across this issue before? I receive a 200 response but the body contains nothing. I am able to hit this test route locally (/api/Test/) so the route is correct and I can hit my swagger documentation in the production application (/swagger/index.html).

I have adjusted my database connections to make sure that nothing is interfering and remove my SignalR code. A newly create .NET Core 3.1 Web Api will hit the weather controller correctly but I cannot get a simple string to return anything even though I am receiving a 200 response code.

[image]

I refactored my database connection as I saw it was causing errors in the diagnose problems in Azure. I moved my CORs policy for SignalR and also removed it.

I reordered my AddScoped and AddSingletons.

A string to be returned in a the most simple HttpGet

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access your swagger site `https://your_app_name.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html#/` and it works well.

It means you have successfully. But I haven't seens the server information from your http request in the picture. So I guess you may use the linux environment. And there are some different behaviors between windows and linux for swagger project.

When you debug the project, the default url is:

```
 https://localhost:port/swagger(/index.html),
```

but in linux, the default url is:

```
 https://localhost:port
```

That's why you face this issue. Please use below code to change the start url.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Test1 Api v1");
        // Add this line, it will work for you
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: The suggested changes do not work as intended. I cannot find SwaggerEnpoint in RoutePrefix in the intellisense to try.

Comment: I also tried deploying to the Windows environment in Azure and I got the same results when navigating to /api/Test.

Comment: Switched over to Swashbuckle instead of NSwag to do the configuration changes that you were speaking of, I am able to view the SwaggerUI on the initial load. However the /api/Test route is still not working. I still receive a 200 without the appropriate response.